# C# IBM MQ WEBSPHERE MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have setup the IBM Websphere MQ in my localhost pc and follow the tutorial from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-quick-start-with-C-Sharp-and-websphere-mq/)  and [here](https://2freeclear.wordpress.com/2014/11/05/ibm-websphere-mq-connection-with-ccdt-file/)

When i run the code it always give me the same error.

```
    Error 2035 : MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

when it reach this line ;

```
    MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QM_TEST", props);
```

I already set the MCA UserID in the server-connection channel : mqm and use it in my code

```
    props.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "mqm");
```

And from what i read on the internet when we set MCA UserID it should override
what is provided by client.But still the problem occurred.

Not sure if it related, but Im using Websphere Version: 7.5.0.2 and Windows 10 Pro.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What channel do you connect to?  Is it a channel that starts with `SYSTEM`?

Comment: yes. i created a server-connection channel under SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> props.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "mqm");

Bad idea, absolutely not recommended.  That UserId is for the exclusive use of MQ and NOT applications.

> ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)

Really, really bad and stupid idea.  You are disabling security in MQ.  So, you just want anybody or hackers to get whatever they want from your messaging system.

Comment: yeah..i thought so too. but due to time constraint, i want to proceed with the development first. And i found this pdf about how to set auth rules. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041997&aid=1

Comment: If you don't have security on in DEV then when you go to QA nothing will work and you will turn security off - the same is true for PROD.  Do your testing in DEV with security on so that when you deploy it to other environments, it will be easy.

Comment: Just saying it's not a good idea isn't really helpful. Better solution?

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: You have the MQAdmin use setmqaut to add the correct permissions for the UserId (or better to the group), so the UserId can connect and open the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by disabling chanel authentication

ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)

Comment: Disabling `CHLAUTH` is not recommended even in Test/Dev environments.  It would be better to add `CHLAUTH` rules to allow the connection in the way you want it setup.  It is also not recommended to set the `MCAUSER` to `mqm` on the `SVRCONN` channel.